# Send keyboard event from developer PC to Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

When running an app via Flutter run or VC, we see the flutter console log of the app.

Is it possible to send keyboard events from the developer PC to the app via STDIN which we receive in the app (without VM extensions).

The idea is to use this during development to trigger certain actions in the app.

Comment: question isn't clear, be specific,  sending / receiving the input to / from where?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building a simple TELNET server into the app. This I way, I communicate with the app running on a phone for debugging purposes.